# Tier 'savePercent' Calculation Based on 'Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price'

Tags: tierprice

By default, on a simple product with tier pricing, each tier price 'percent saved' is calculated based on the 'Item Price'.

[image: Before]

I want to recalculate the 'percent saved' to display/calculate the percent saved based on the 'Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price'

[image: After]

On this file:
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\tierprices.phtml
This is the line of code that displays the tier price percent saved:

```
<span class="percent tier-<?php echo $_index;?>"><?php echo $_price['savePercent']?></span>
```

NEW FOUND INFO:

I found this file: app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product

Which shows the formula which calculates the 'savePercent':

```
$price['savePercent'] = ceil(100 - ((100 / $productPrice) * $price['price']));
```

I have been trying to add:

```
$_msrpPrice = $this->helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,true)
```

Then replace 'productPrice' with '_msrpPrice' or 'msrpPrice' but it breaks the page.

Can anyone point me to:

1) Where can I modify this formula to display the % save off of the 'Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price'

2) Hopefully give me the variable to replace or even a script I can add?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

1) Create a local version of the price.html at: app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Price.php

2) Change this code:

```
$price['savePercent'] = ceil(100 - ((100 / $productPrice) * $price['price']));
```

TO (you can make your own notes):

```
// MONJ: set originalPrice variable equal to products MSRP. If MSRP is equal or less than zero, use the product price as originalPrice.
$originalPrice = $product->getMsrp();
if ($originalPrice <= 0.00) {
$originalPrice = $productPrice;
}

// MONJ: Calculate percent saved off MSRP
$price['savePercent'] = ceil(100 - ((100 / $originalPrice) * $price['price']));
```

Hope this helps someone.